# Session timeout in production but not locally

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, session, timeout

I have an ASP.NET WebForms application written in C# that runs as intended when running the program locally. The session times out after 60 minutes, which is what it is configured to do in web.config.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout ="60"></sessionState>
```

However, the published version which is hosted on Azure server times out after about 5 minutes.

What is the issue here?

Comment: `InProc` sessions are problematic - especially when dealing with cloud / web farms / web gardens. Why are you using `InProc`?

Comment: I'm still fairly new to development so I don't really know the difference between the various session states but InProc is the default. Also, when I tried changing it to StateServer mode I got an exception "Unable to make the session state request to the session state server."

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the In-Proc session mode which would store session state in an individual web server's memory. Moreover, if the web server instance going down due to failures would result in the session data loss.

Since you could scale up your web app to multiple instances, using In-Proc session mode is not a good practice for your to host your web app on Azure, which could not share session state between multiple instances of your web app.

For a simple way, you could [Configure SQL Server to Store ASP.NET Session State](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317604) or [Session state with Azure Redis cache](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-session-state-caching/). Also, as mentioned in the [article](https://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/distributed-caching#sessionstate), the best solution if you have to use session state is to use a cache provider, such as [Session State Provider for Azure Cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/gg185668.aspx).

Another option for legacy apps is to keep `ARR Affinity` on in the App Service (if you are using them). This effectively sets a cookie on the client when they first connect so the load balancer will always connect them to the same instance, so in-memory session state works.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I'm looking into the information that you sent for other session state modes. However, if I want to continue using InProc I can take advantage of ARR Afifinity, is that correct? Isn't that enabled by default though? So it should have already been working properly

Comment: I checked the cookies and ARRAfinity and ASP.NET_SessionId are actually staying the same. But what I noticed is that the Session_Start event in Global.asax is firing multiple times when in production, so I think that's why the session variables are null. What can be causing this?

Comment: `so in-memory session state works.` Assuming the web server never restarts. :)

Comment: What are some things that can cause the web server to restart? Because I have a separate ASP.NET application hosted on Azure, set up the same way using InProc session state, and I don't have the issue of it timing out after 5 minutes or so